# Grouping two classes in a dataframe with start and stop time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Dataframe consist of time (from a video) and label (based on occurrence of an action in the video) . I would like to get a list for each label which shows the start and finish time for every label.

| Time(sec) | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 76 | 0 |
| 77 | 0 |
| 78 | 0 |
| 79 | 1 |
| 80 | 1 |
| 81 | 1 |
| 82 | 0 |
| 83 | 0 |
| 84 | 1 |

expecting output should be like this:

```
Label_Class_0 = [[76,78],[82,83],...]
Label_Class_1 = [[79,81],[84,..],...]
```

Thank you

Comment: Are Label_Class_x lists themselves? Where are the start and finish times you mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use from this code:

```py
df['merger']=df.label.ne(df.label.shift(1)).cumsum()

df =df.groupby(by=['merger']).agg({'label':'first', 'time':['min', 'max']}).reset_index()
df.columns=['a','b','c']

df['w']=pd.Series(zip(df.b,df.c))

list0=df[df.a.eq(0)].w.to_list()
list1=df[df.a.eq(1)].w.to_list()
```